# How to check for specific text in a variable

Tags: string, powershell, contains

I have a script that I have wrote that reaches out to a remote machine or the local machine and grabs the environment variables and puts them into a file.

the issue is I have Internal and External hosts. Each hostname would end in either INT or EXT. if the command runs on any host that has EXT in the name it will need to be supplied with my PSCredential object. all other hosts wont work if credentials are used.

My issue is how to determine if the hostname has `"EXT"`in the name or not.

if i put the below into ISE it gives me a true/false and works fine,
But if that variable is being populated from a parameter when the script is called $test end up being what ever the hostname that was entered.

```
$compuername = "HOSTNAME1ext"
$test = $compuername -like  "*ext"
if ($test -eq $true) {Write-Host "yes"} else {Write-Host "no"}
yes
```

But when it is used like this it does not work

```
 [cmdletbinding()]           
param(
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]            
 [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:ComputerName,            
 [string]$Name            
)  
$test = $ComputerName -like "*ext" 
if ($test -eq $true) {
$UNPASSWORD = Get-Credential -UserName "$ComputerName\ACCOUNT" -message "Enter the Password for the ACCOUNT Account";$EnvObj = @(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Environment -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $UNPASSWORD -EA Stop) 
} else {$EnvObj = @(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Environment -ComputerName $ComputerName -EA Stop)}
```

when this is done $test comes back as the hostname entered rather than True or False.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply the `-like` operator to a *collection* of objects, in your example an array of strings, if works as a *filter* operator - ie. it only returns the items that satisfy the condition.

Either change the parameter type:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$ComputerName
```

or connect to each computer one by one:

```
foreach($Name in $ComputerName){
    if($Name -like '*ext'){
        # Ask for Credential
    }
}
```